# formulario angular

Tags: formularios, angular5

Buenas estoy realizando un registro de producto con angular, y en un de los "inputs" quiero agregarle "tags"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta hora no se como hacer que mi formulario se agregen varios "tags" y enviarlos al backend, alguna idea de como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando Angular Material puedes usar los Chips que puedes enviar al backend como un arreglo de string.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/njjrpopbpya?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts